# Any rule of thumb about flagstone size?

Tags: patio

I understand that this is a mater of esthetics and there are different styles of flagstone patio layout - tighter, loser, more uniform, more natural, etc. I'm looking for any rule of thumb range for the size of individual flagstone pieces in a patio. It may be that larger patios can look good with larger pieces. I have been laying them out and I think they are too big. Part of the problem is that there are small pieces filing in gaps and the large pieces make the small ones look very small.

The whole thing is about 125 sq feet and the larger pieces are about 9 sq feet.

[image]

Comment: This is truly an opinion based answer so you may not get very far here since opinion based questions are not in line with the rules, but, if you like the big ones, space them apart like islands surrounded by smaller and smaller pieces. For the most part, you done some very nice piecing together in places. A little strategic cutting with a diamond blade will get you the rest of the way....

Comment: I have found scoring the bottom then breaking provides a rough but straight cut so they still look natural.

Comment: Big pieces are heavier to move. I used much thicker stone , but I broke a few because they were too heavy to locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the size of the pieces matter as much as the uniformity in size between pieces. Granted, the smaller the space, the smaller the size I would use, but the uniformity is your current problem. I'd also recommend putting a weed barrier down under the flagstones unless you're planning on having moss or grass grow between the cracks.